# Use output from last or both layer in a 2 Layer GRU RNN classifier?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm experimenting with tensorflow. I'm trying to build a classification system based on a sequence as input. I made a network existing of 2 layers of regular RNN and 1 layer of GRU cells (MultiRNNCell in tensorflow) Then I intended to couple a softmax output to the hidden state of my last GRU cell. Now I noticed that when I take the last state from the MultiRNNCell output. It's 3x the size as the hidden layer I specified for my GRU cell. I'm guessing that this is the state of all 3 RNN layers concatenated. Is this correct? If so, does it make sense to couple the state of all the layers to the softmax output? Or should I only do it on the state of the last GRU cell.

I tested both cases on some small toy dataset and the algorithm seems to learn in both cases but I'm not sure what makes most sense in a real situation.

Some code how I specified the RNN model

```
cell = rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(RNNlayer_size)]*2  +[rnn_cell.GRUCell(RNNlayer_size)])
outputs, states = rnn.rnn(cell, inputs,dtype = tf.float32)

## couple last stat to a softmax classifier
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([RNNlayer_size*3,output_size]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([output_size]))
y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, output_size])
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.nn.xw_plus_b(states[-1],W, b))
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit of a code extract from your example to make this easier to answer?  Thanks!

Comment: Done, see above for the changes to reflect the last state of my model + code.

Comment: Any progress on this?